# Bluetooth Instability

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, microchip

I'm using RN4020 BLE From Microchip  to transmit a reading from the ADC of the Module itself to the phone.
I put the module into sleep mode then read the ADC for 2 ms then allow it to be awake in 9 us to transmit the data. the value is put in a private characteristic that is readable and notifiable and on the phone side i use nRF master control 
The problem is: although when i press " notify " in the phone side after connecting and the value update pretty fast as intended i guess but when i press disconnect it does not remove the connection, the Bluetooth in my phone kept freezing and even after i click disconnect the data kept changing, any guess?
Note : i'm new for BLE

Comment: What phone? What phone OS.  Android BLE is notoriously buggy...  You may want to check with a more standard piece of hardware to see what the app dose in a similar situation.

Comment: Android 4.3 Lenovo tablet